# Cantor - No set is equinumerous with its power set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Theorem**:

No set is equinumerous with its power set.

**Proof**:

Let $A$ be a set. We want to show that if $f: A \to \mathcal{P}A$ (a random function) then $f$ is not surjective.

We define the set $D=\{ x \in A: x \notin f(x)\}$ and obviously $D \in \mathcal{P}A$.

We assume that there is an $a \in A$ such that $f(a)=D$.

Then we have:

$$a \notin D \leftrightarrow a \notin f(a) \leftrightarrow a \in D, \text{ contradiction}$$

Therefore for each $x \in A, f(x) \notin D$, i.e. $f$ is not surjective.

Could you explain me the proof from the point where we assume that there is an $a \in A$ such that $f(a)=D$?

We have show that $D \in \mathcal{P}A$ and we want to show that $D \notin f(A)$ in order to show that $\mathcal{P}A$ isn't the image of $f$.
Why do we do it like that? Why do we assume an $a \in A$ such that $f(a)=D$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if you prove that $D\in \mathcal PA$ and $D\notin f(A)$ proves that $f(A)\neq \mathcal PA$, which is the definition of surjectivity of $f$.

You prove that $D\notin f(A)$ using the definition of $f(a)$: since $D\in f(A) \iff \exists a\in A: f(a)=D$, you only need to prove that there does not exist such an $a\in A$ that $f(a)=D$. You prove this by contradiction, i.e. you assume:

$$\exists a\in A: f(a)=D$$

and arrive at a contradiction, meaning you prove that the statement is false. Since the statement is equivalent to the statement $D\in f(A)$, this statement is also untrue.

Comment: Yes, I have understood it.. I haven't understood why in order to prove that $D \notin f(A)$, we  assume that there is an $a \in A$ such that $f(a)=D$.

Comment: @evinda I edited my answer, is it any clearer?

Comment: 5xum I see.. And how can we continue after having set that $f(a)=D=\{x \in A: x \notin f(x) \}$ ?

Comment: @evinda you do not have $D=f(a)$, that is the whole point. You define a set $D=\{x\in A: x\notin f(x)\}$. Then you prove that there is no such $a\in A$ for which $f(a)=D$ would be true, therefore proving that $D\notin f(A)$.

Comment: 5xum How could we prove that there is no such an an $a \in A$ ?

Comment: @evinda By assuming that such an $a\in A$ exists and arriving at a contradiction.

Comment: @evinda Do you know what a "proof by contradiction" is?

Comment: 5xum We assume that there is an $a \in A$ such that $f(a)=D$ and want to find a contradiction. But what can we say assuming that $f(a)=D$? What would hold if this equality was true?

Comment: @Evinda **Hint:** read the 5th line of the proof you wrote (the one after "then we have")

Comment: 5xum I have read it but I haven't understood why it holds unter the assumption that $f(a)=D$... :/

Comment: @evinda If $f(a) = D$, then is $a$ an element of $D$?

Comment: 5xum We assume that $a \in A$... If $a \in D$ then $a \notin f(a)$. But how can we determine if the last relation holds?

Comment: It holds that $a \in D \leftrightarrow a \notin f(a)$. But why is this also equivalent to $a \notin D$ ?

Comment: @evinda The point is that if $f(a)=D$, then, by definition of $D$, you know that if $a\in D$, then $a\notin f(a)$ meaning $a\notin D$. On the other hand, if $a\notin D$, then $a\notin f(a)$, meaning that by the definition of $D$, $a\in D=f(a)$. Therefore, both $a\in D$ and $a\notin D$ lead to a contradiction.

Comment: @evinda $a\in D \iff a\notin f(a)\iff a\notin D$: The first $\iff$ is true because $D$ is defined as such, i.e. for every element $x\in A$, you have $a\in D\iff x\notin f(x)$. The second $\iff$ is true because $f(a)=D$, so for every $x$, you know that $x\notin f(a)\iff x\notin D$.

Comment: 5xum I got it now... Thanks a lot!!! Could I also ask you something else about Set Theory?

Comment: @evinda Of course, but please, ask it in a separate question. If my answer is what you needed, then accept it and ask a new question, that's how the site works...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113586/how-can-we-deduce-that-0-1-omega-sim-mathcalp-omega That's my question..